# MySQL GROUP BY and conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, group-by

I would like to group the table below and return parts_number while checking the option value.
That is, for parts with same parts_number, same option value be grouped together. No mixing parts_number with different option values.

```
parts | parts_number | option
A | 100 |1
B | 120 |1
A | 100 |0
C | 110 |1
B | 120 |1
C | 110 |0
A | 100 |0
A | 100 |0
A | 100 |1
```

In the case above I should have my results returning rows as below:

```
parts | parts_number | option
A | 100 |1
B | 120 |1
A | 100 |0
C | 110 |1
C | 110 |0

A => 2
B => 1
C => 2
```

Note the grouping while not mixing parts of different options.
I have tried to group_by parts_number but I am stuck at the point where I have to cater for my options too.

I am using PHP (CodeIgniter) and MySQL. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to add HTML tags to format code.  If you want to show us some code just put it in a code block and Stack Overflow will colour code it nicely for you.

Comment: I can group_by parts_number but how do I check/add the option value in this query SELECT* FROM my_table GROUP BY parts_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT parts, parts_number, option
FROM parts
GROUP BY parts, parts_number, option
```

should work.

Comment: @nairobicoder: it means that those rows where the parts, parts_number and option values are the same are all treated as part of a group.  So it is grouping by multiple attributes, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@YogendraSingh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938020); however it's hard to tell from your question whether you (also?) want the count of the grouped results, which can be obtained with:

```sql
SELECT parts, COUNT(DISTINCT parts_number, option) FROM my_table GROUP BY parts
```